# JavaScript error msg : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript

The below javascript code is displaying nothing,although this code works by Fiddle perfectly. The javascript console gives me 2 error messages which I don't understand: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null, so anyone understands the reason of the error messages and how can I get my code worked so it will calculate & display stuff that users will choose?

The code is:

```
var numericalValues = new Array();
numericalValues["Alot"]= 4;
numericalValues["NotMuch"]= 2;
numericalValues["NoSometimes"]= 3;
numericalValues["Hate"]= 0;
numericalValues["Chocolate"]= 4;
numericalValues["Carrot"]= 0;
numericalValues["Both"]= 2;
numericalValues["None"]= 0;


function getScoreChoco()
{
var scoreChoco = 0;
var form = document.forms["form"];
var choco = form.elements["choco"];
for(var i=0; i<choco.length; i++)
{
    if(choco[i].checked)
    {
    scoreChoco = numericalValues[choco[i].value];
    break;
    }

}
return scoreChoco;
}

function getScoreCake()
{
var scoreCake = 0;
var form = document.forms["form"];
var cake = form.elements["cake"];

for(var i=0; i<cake.length; i++)
{
  if(cake[i].checked)
  {
  scoreCake = numericalValues[cake[i].value];
  break;
  }

}
return scoreCake;
}


function getTotal()
{

var totalScore = getScoreCake() + getScoreChoco();


document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your total score is: "+totalScore;



document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=getTotal;
}
```

Okay the HTML code for it:

```
<form id="form" name="form">
<fieldset id="controls">
<p>Do you like chocolate?
<label>Yes a lot </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="alot" value="Alot" checked="true">

<label>Not that much </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="notMuch" value="NotMuch">
<label>No, but still I don't mind eating it sometimes </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="noSometimes" value="NoSometimes">

 <label>No, I hate it </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="hate" value="Hate">
</p>
<p>Do you prefer chocolate cake or carrot cake?
<label>chocolate </label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="chocolate" value="Chocolate" checked="true">

<label>Carrot </label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="carrot" value="Carrot">

<label>Both</label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="both" value="Both">

<label>None </label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="none" value="None">
</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" name="Calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" />
</p>
    <p id="result"></p>

    </form>
```

Comment: what does `document.getElementById('calculate')` return at the point it is called?

Comment: the `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is a network error. Is there another important file that is "included" into your page somehow? Like a css file, another javascript file, etc? And the onclick error message means that the thing you tried to set a property of an object that doesn't exist, nameingly, `document.getElementById('calculate')` Therefore, I am inclined to think that the `calculate` element is somehow loaded from another file, which is not being loaded, therefore causing the error message. So, to help us narrow it down, could you tell us all of the files that are being used in this page?

Comment: @ Daniel A. White, I have also posted the HTML code for it.

Comment: try entering `document.getElementById('calculate')` into the console (you can open it by doing CTRL+SHIFT+J in chrome). What does it return?

Comment: you mean to put the `}` before the `document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=getTotal;`, right?

Comment: @ Markasoftware, thanks for the hint, yeah for some reason I attached by accident the wrong css file,I actually didn't need it, now I have got just 1 error message saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null, I have also edited my original post and added the HTML form.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=getTotal;` be after the closing `}` of the `getTotal` function? Otherwise the onclick will not be set until getTotal is called, and it will never be called because there is nothing calling it. A typo?

Comment: If I enter that line you said, then I am getting this ==> document.getElementById('calculate')

Comment: @ Markasoftware, just a second I am trying, sorry I am a bit slow with these sort of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your javascript code is located above the HTML code. Therefore, when you try to access `document.getElementById('calculate')`, the html code has not been parsed yet, so there is no element with id `calculate` yet, so it returns undefined. Try putting the javascript code at the end of the body tag instead of wherever it is (probably in the head tag, im guessing)

Comment: I have got an external js, that is attached to the head part of HTML, now I have changed the position of { and it looks like this:still javascript code gives nothing back.

Comment: function getTotal()
{

var totalScore = getScoreCake() + getScoreChoco();


document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your total score is: "+totalScore;


}
document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=getTotal;

Comment: that's how it should be, i think

Comment: I am still having the error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null , I don't want to sound cheeky, but could you simply copy and paste the html code and the javascript code in your notepad and see what I mean with the error message?

Comment: yes, but it's better to post a jsfiddle (see jsfiddle.net) for things like this

Comment: yep, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/J4YA3/ check out the link, and you'll see it works, no error

Comment: @ Markasoftware, at jsfiddle it works...That's why's drivng me crazy.

Comment: @ Markasoftware, I have to have it on my notepad, on the notepad it's not working, try it for yourself.

Comment: and you've included the javascript file at the end of the body tag?

Comment: @ Markasoftware, nope I put it in the head part, very begin.

Comment: this answer tells you to put it at the end of the body tag! Put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="whatever.js"></script>` at the BOTTOM of the BODY tag!

Comment: @ Markasoftware, OMG, it worked! Thanks, you made me 1 happy woman!